# Tapestry error: The resource path was not within an aliased path

Tags: javascript, assets, tapestry

I am not a Java developer and forced to work with Tapestry 5.3.8. 
I am able to use assets like css, images and a fav icon in my web page. I do this by injecting them in my page like this:

```
@Inject
@Path("context:static/img/logo.png")
private Asset logo;

@Inject
@Path("context:static/img/favicon.ico")
private Asset favIcon;
```

This works without problems. Although it works, I am not convinced the assets are in the right folder. Should they be placed in folder 'static'?

Now I want to add a Javascript file. This is what I did:

```
@Import(library = "context:static/js/additional.js")
public class Master {
// ...
}
```

The file is found, but I runtime i get the following error: "The resource path was not within an aliased path".

From what I understand is that I need to create an alias for the path where my Javscript file is located, but how?

I guess this must be done in method "contributeClasspathAssetAliasManager" in CiAppModule.java. Is this right, and what should I add?

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried to use a `context:` asset for a javascript file. Tapestry makes classpath assets available under the `assets/` alias which is possibly what this error is referring to. See the mention of 'asset fingerprinting' [here](http://tapestry.apache.org/assets.html)

A possible souition is:

```
package foo.bar.components;

@Import(library = "additional.js")
public class Master {
```

And then have `foo/bar/components/additional.js` available on the classpath. For maven / gradle this will mean the file lives at `src/main/resources/foo/bar/components/additional.js`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is not exactly the solution to the problem I had, but the information about the file locations is very useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in this part:

```
@Import(library = "context:static/js/additional.js")
```

When I change it into

```
@Import(library = {"context:static/js/additional.js"})
```

it works.

Thanks to Tapestry's error reporting, this was not clear at all. Grrrr.

Comment: It's impossible that this fixed your problem. This is a core language feature of java, for an annotation property which is an array you can choose to leave out the curly brackets for single element arrays. Both are equivelant.